# Check if URL available or not using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one URL like `www.testsite.com/mypage`.I need to check if URL is exist or not using AngularJS.

Is it possible. Any one please suggest.

Comment: Available in what sense? Getting 200 response? Not getting 404? Is 500 considered as 'available'?

Comment: If getting 200 the URLis success .if i get other status code the URL is failure.In that sense Cam i use AngularJs.Can you please give one example

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap this test by using a server-side api (or service) because embedding this kind of test in JavaScript is considered as cross-domain-query (could be considered as an attack).

For example, consider you have written a wrapper under `/myRemoteSiteTester`
then I would try whith somethings like that:

```
$http.get('/api/myRemoteSiteTester', {params: {target: myUrl}}) 
       .success(function(data) {
              alert(data);
        });
```