# How to check if a url is accessible or not in angular 8?

Tags: angular

I am looking for guidance on how to check if a url is accessible or not(response code 200 ) from angular?

I looked at [Check if URL available or not using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512488/check-if-url-available-or-not-using-angularjs) which has the following suggestion but it doesn't work,is there a simpler way to do this in angular 8?

```
$http.get('/api/myRemoteSiteTester', {params: {target: myUrl}}) 
       .success(function(data) {
              alert(data);
        });
```

Comment: The `$http.get` is a promise-based service only available in AngularJS 1.x. The Angular 2+ frameworks use Observable-based services for XHRs.

Comment: @georgeawg -- how exactly to use Observable-based services for this specific case?do you mind sharing an example?